# Program cannot be run in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have written a C++ game.

It works perfectly on a distro where I built it (openSUSE), but on another (Lubuntu) it can't run.
I use this launcher:

```
chmod +x Trigonium
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""
./Trigonium
```

And it says:
./Launcher.sh: line 3: ./Trigonium: cannot open binary file

I get the same error when I try to run directly.

Comment: Hint: Compare the results of commands: `uname -a` and `file Trigonium`

Comment: Launcher.sh you say? Try looking at your file with a text editor.

Comment: Is possible to differ type of operating system or is not installed some libraries. Try to recompile in this new distro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it the same binary on both systems?

Is one system 32-bit and the other 64-bit?  Check with `uname -a` as Gowtham suggests.